# C Macro change every other time

Tags: c-preprocessor, c89

Can a C macro be expressed to expand to a different code block every other time, so that the macro that is written stays the same? (aka without macro variables or macro1 / macro2)

I want

```
macro
macro
macro
macro

to expand to

function1();
function2();
function1();
function2();
```

I tried to use #undef followed by #define to alternate what the macro pastes, but quickly found that you cannot have directives in macros.

Comment: You can use `__COUNTER__` macro (although I'm not sure it is in C89 standard, but C99+ have it), but wrapping it around is a different story. You can use inline function that takes counter argument and uses `cnt%2` to figure out which function to call, but that's not really great. What's your actual use case?

Comment: I'm writing a bit of custom debugging. This particular macro is supposed to call start and end of a hardware timer to get execution time (which I need a lot). Creating "Performance brackets", which integrates really nice into a text editor.

Currently I do this at run time by checking a true / false on whether timer start has run or not. I want to skip the check. As I understand it normally  doesn't matter, as it get's optimized away, but the debugging is run without any optimization. A single int if condition doesn't matter in the grand scheme of things of course.

Comment: Would you consider a different approach than a macro that toggles?  You can implement this logic easily, and in a much more controlled fashion, with `#include` of a file designed to toggle the bracket state.

Comment: Just to get the rules straight (I already expect that it does not help you). Could you do `#define macro function1(); function2();` and then only use the macro twice instead of four times? Probably not, but why exactly?

Comment: @Yunnosch I want the macro to call a function that serves as a start point and end point for performance analysis. So a macro that alternates defines start(); and end();  , but using the same macro name. #define macro1 start(); and #define macro2 end(); defeats the purpose. __COUNTER__ is not supported everywhere. I guess it cannot be done. I will just check a bool value at run-time.

Comment: This is just an opinion, not saying that your concept is wrong: If I would want to encapsulate code parts in pairs of macros, then I would actually WANT them to be two different macros. I do not trust anybody (especially not myself) with getting the count from 0 to 2 right in all cases, situations and causalities.

Comment: Can you move the location of where you need to solve this? What I mean is do not try to expand two different things from the same macro. Expand the macro always to function1or2() and then inside that function either call function1() or function2(), depending on what was called last time.

Comment: @Yunnosch As stated in the 2nd comment, I'm already doing that. I wanted to get rid of the boolean check. Since the time taking is from a hardware clock I want to get rid of the influence of that bool check.